# My box is under attack

Tags: ssh

now I'm logged into my digitalocean's box and I can clearly see this in my log and I guess somekind of script is trying to break in:

```
Mar  8 13:25:25 sshd[11311]: Invalid user schedule from 216.157.31.144
Mar  8 13:25:25 sshd[11311]: input_userauth_request: invalid user schedule [preauth]
Mar  8 13:25:25 sshd[11311]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar  8 13:25:25 sshd[11311]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=216.157.31.144 
Mar  8 13:25:27 sshd[11311]: Failed password for invalid user schedule from 216.157.31.144 port 32774 ssh2
Mar  8 13:25:27 sshd[11311]: Received disconnect from 216.157.31.144: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  8 13:26:26 sshd[11313]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for new.mega.nn.ru [93.183.127.194] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Mar  8 13:26:26 sshd[11313]: Invalid user toor from 93.183.127.194
Mar  8 13:26:26 sshd[11313]: input_userauth_request: invalid user toor [preauth]
Mar  8 13:26:26 sshd[11313]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar  8 13:26:26 sshd[11313]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=93.183.127.194 
Mar  8 13:26:28 sshd[11313]: Failed password for invalid user toor from 93.183.127.194 port 48789 ssh2
Mar  8 13:26:28 sshd[11313]: Received disconnect from 93.183.127.194: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  8 13:28:08 sshd[11315]: Invalid user administrator from 24.24.96.163
Mar  8 13:28:08 sshd[11315]: input_userauth_request: invalid user administrator [preauth]
Mar  8 13:28:08 sshd[11315]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar  8 13:28:08 sshd[11315]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=24.24.96.163 
Mar  8 13:28:09 sshd[11315]: Failed password for invalid user administrator from 24.24.96.163 port 49685 ssh2
Mar  8 13:28:10 sshd[11315]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar  8 13:28:12 sshd[11315]: Failed password for invalid user administrator from 24.24.96.163 port 49685 ssh2
Mar  8 13:28:12 sshd[11315]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar  8 13:28:14 sshd[11315]: Failed password for invalid user administrator from 24.24.96.163 port 49685 ssh2
Mar  8 13:28:14 sshd[11315]: Connection closed by 24.24.96.163 [preauth]
Mar  8 13:28:14 sshd[11315]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=24.24.96.163 
Mar  8 13:28:18 sshd[11317]: Did not receive identification string from 80.78.102.189
Mar  8 13:28:19 sshd[11318]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for zbmo-ll.umn.ru [80.78.102.189] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Mar  8 13:28:19 sshd[11318]: Invalid user admin from 80.78.102.189
Mar  8 13:28:19 sshd[11318]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Mar  8 13:28:19 sshd[11318]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar  8 13:28:19 sshd[11318]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=80.78.102.189 
Mar  8 13:28:21 sshd[11318]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 80.78.102.189 port 50953 ssh2
Mar  8 13:28:21 sshd[11318]: Connection closed by 80.78.102.189 [preauth]
Mar  8 13:31:03 sshd[11331]: Invalid user schiko from 216.157.31.144
Mar  8 13:31:03 sshd[11331]: input_userauth_request: invalid user schiko [preauth]
Mar  8 13:31:03 sshd[11331]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar  8 13:31:03 sshd[11331]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=216.157.31.144 
Mar  8 13:31:04 sshd[11331]: Failed password for invalid user schiko from 216.157.31.144 port 20222 ssh2
Mar  8 13:31:04 sshd[11331]: Received disconnect from 216.157.31.144: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  8 13:31:48 sshd[11333]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=125.88.177.90  user=root
Mar  8 13:31:50 sshd[11333]: Failed password for root from 125.88.177.90 port 27353 ssh2
Mar  8 13:31:55  sshd[11333]: last message repeated 2 times
Mar  8 13:31:55 sshd[11333]: Received disconnect from 125.88.177.90: 11:  [preauth]
Mar  8 13:31:55 sshd[11333]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=125.88.177.90  user=root
Mar  8 13:31:58 sshd[11335]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=125.88.177.90  user=root
Mar  8 13:32:00 sshd[11335]: Failed password for root from 125.88.177.90 port 57212 ssh2
Mar  8 13:32:05  sshd[11335]: last message repeated 2 times
Mar  8 13:32:05 sshd[11335]: Received disconnect from 125.88.177.90: 11:  [preauth]
Mar  8 13:32:05 sshd[11335]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=125.88.177.90  user=root
Mar  8 13:32:08 sshd[11337]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=125.88.177.90  user=root
Mar  8 13:32:10 sshd[11337]: Failed password for root from 125.88.177.90 port 35022 ssh2
Mar  8 13:32:15  sshd[11337]: last message repeated 2 times
Mar  8 13:32:15 sshd[11337]: Received disconnect from 125.88.177.90: 11:  [preauth]
```

I see that multiple IP's are trying to access it to get in!

After doing `lsof -i | less`

I see this somewhere in the end of output, and do I guess right that this 125-ip is in or not?

```
sshd     11548     root    3r  IPv4 5046701      0t0  TCP 178.62.190.116:ssh->125.88.177.90:23216 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd     11549     sshd    3u  IPv4 5046701      0t0  TCP 178.62.190.116:ssh->125.88.177.90:23216 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I'm accessing the droplet with my private key as passwordless ssh loggin, but as I'm aware root user can still login if the password is guessed, right?

Comment: All publicly exposed ssh services are under _attack_ (trying common passwords for common users) and have been for decades, it's not only you. Only allow ssh access to the users who need it and which you can trust to choose strong passwords and/or keep their private key safe and protected with a strong passphrase. Setup fail2ban or equivalent, and/or use some port-knocking mechanism. Using a different port number can also help reduce the load induced by those probes.

Comment: thanks @StéphaneChazelas for advices, will for sure change the port# for starters that sounds solid ,, the port-knocking sounds hard to implement and do not know about it enough,,

Comment: In all fairness, I'm also seeing an increase of attack attempts on digitalocean, specifically from new.mega.nn.ru.... one IP gets banned, another pops up. They have been hammering my droplet for 3 or 4 days already....

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any information about your `sshd_config`, but good place to start, you are using publickey authentication is deny password authentication altogether and deny root login:

```
PermitRootLogin no  # or  without-password  if you need that login
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

If password authentication is not allowed, you will get rid of almost all of the attacks. It is not feasible to attack on public key authentication.